# Python class error: "str object is not callable"

Tags: python-2.7

I was just practicing class and object
The code is
[image]

I already know the second function def name is overlapped since name is already set as self.name. but I am not sure how it makes error.

Can anyone tell how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty descriptive; strings aren't callable, functions are. I believe Python will look for variables within the class before it checks if there are functions with a given name. Thus, the *string* `name` is found but because it has `()` added to it, python then tries to call it like a function and fails.

Simply rename the function or the variable. You could use `self._name` as the variable name if you want to indicate that it's private and shouldn't be changed - at least not from outside the class. You'll also have to write `print "The University name is %s" % (self._name)` (and `self.rank`).

Answer (score 0):

You already have a variable called `name` in your class `University`, so the program is trying to call `"University of America"()`, which triggers an error. Thus, change the function name to something like `print_name`:

```
class University():
        def __init__(self, name, rank):
                self.name = name
                self.rank = rank

        def print_name(self):
                print "The University name is %s" % (self.name)
                print "This University is ranked at %s" % (self.rank)
```

---

```
>>> users = University("University of America", "#1")
>>> users.name #The string of the name
'University of America'
>>> users.print_name()
The University name is University of America
This University is ranked at #1
>>>
```